# How to perform the mv equivalent of yes | cp -rf on directories?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, files, mv

Using the below directory tree as an example, what is the best way to move the contents of `directory/folderA` to `directory`.

How to overwrite a file if a file with the same name exists in the destination, for example: `directory/folderA/2017/06/info.log` and `directory/2017/06/info.log`.

```
directory
|-- folderA
|   |-- 2017
|   |   |-- 06
|   |
|   |-- 2016
|   |   |-- 12
|   |   |-- 11
|   |   |-- 10
|
|-- 2017
|   |-- 04
|   |-- 05
|   |-- 06
|
|-- 2016
|   |
```

Comment: I am looking for the move equivalent of the `yes | cp -rf`. This is so that the data does not have to be rewritten. The goal is also to preserve files in the destination folders that do not exist in the source directory.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `rsync -a --remove-source-files src/ dest` ? A simple test shows that anything existing in `dest` but not in `src` will be preserved. (Note the slash after `src`. It is required here.)

Taking preservation a step further, you can add `--ignore-existing` so files in `dest` will not be overwritten even if they also exist in `src`. But then you may be left with files in `src` since `--remove-source-files` only applies to files successfully transferred to the destination.

Generally speaking, `rsync` is a very powerful tool with numerous options. (And, proportionally, a bit of a learning curve...though the case here is pretty straightforward, it seems.) If someone has thought of a copying scenario before there's a decent chance it's covered in `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -cv /parent_folder/subfolder/* -f - I tar -xv --overwrite /parent_folder/
```

use tar to pack whole directory and pipe to unar in parent folder might be the best choice （add -j both before pipe and after if you want filter the tar file through bzip）

—overwrite :overwrite existing file with file extracted from the tar file